# How to get merged cells from XWPFTableCell (Apache POI)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I read Word table and use Apache POI (classes: XWPFTable, XWPFTableRow, XWPFTableCell). I need to get all merged (child) cells to show them into swing JTable.

```
    XWPFTable table = - got from docx-file
    List<XWPFTableRow> rows = table.getRows();
    XWPFTableCell cell = rows.get(0).getCell(0);
```

How to get all merged (child) cells from this cell?

Comment: POI XWPF API does not directly expose the merge state of the table cells. You can access it by using the lower level XMLBeans generated classes (classes with packages starting with org.openxmlformats). From XWPFTableCell you can call getCTTc().getTcPr(). If this is non-null, you can call getCellMerge() on that value.